# Magit error during commit on Windows

Tags: magit

I have been getting an error when trying to commit using magit. I stage my change with `a`, then on commit `cc` I get the message:

```
Opening output file: No such file or directory, c:/Users/myuname/.emacs.d/server/server
```

If I ignore the message and attempt the commit `cc` again I get the message:

```
There was a problem with the editor '"c:/ProgramData/chocolately/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacsclient.exe"'. ... [Hit $ to see buffer magit-process: .emacs.d for details]
```

After pressing `$` I see the magit process buffer containing:

```
1 C:/ProgramData/chocolately/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacsclient.exe ... "commit" "--"

error: There was a problem with the editor '"c:/ProgramData/chocolately/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacsclient.exe"'. Please suply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I've found similar problems around the web (such as [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32387/cant-commit-on-windows-using-magit) one) but they usually state that it is a bug which has been fixed in more recent versions of emacs/magit. I'm running versions that are more recent than when these answers were posted, so they haven't been helpful to me.

My current system is:

- Windows 10
- GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-mingw32) of 2017-09-13 ([emacs64](https://chocolatey.org/packages/emacs64) package from chocolatey)
- Magit 20180517.1345, Git 2.17.0.windows.1, Emacs 25.2.1, windows-nt

Please let me know if there is any other useful information that I can provide. I'm not very experienced with debugging in emacs, so please excuse anything basic that I've overlooked.

---

EDIT

Here is the with-editor-debug buffer:

```
with-editor: c:/Users/jrm978/.emacs.d/elpa/with-editor-20180414.757/with-editor.el
emacs: c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacs (25.3.1)
system:
  system-type: windows-nt
  system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32
  system-configuration-options: --prefix=/tmp/emacs --without-imagemagick --without-dbus --with-modules 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g0'
server:
  server-running-p: nil
  server-process: #<process server>
  server-use-tcp: t
  server-name: server
  server-socket-dir: nil
    WARNING: not an accessible directory
  server-auth-dir: ~\.emacs.d\server\
    ERROR: not an accessible directory
with-editor-emacsclient-executable:
 value:   c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacsclient.exe (25.3)
 default: c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacsclient.exe (25.3)
 funcall: c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacsclient.exe (25.3)
path:
  $PATH: "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2\\Bin\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;;C:\\Program Files\\Tcl\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\vim\\vim80;C:\\tools\\miniconda3;C:\\tools\\miniconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\OpenSees;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\mpv.install\\tools;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\SIMULIA\\Abaqus\\Commands;C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\site\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\bin;C:\\Users\\jrm978\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\jrm978\\AppData\\Local\\Pandoc\\;C:\\Users\\jrm978\\hunspell\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox;;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\clisp-2.49"
  exec-path: (c:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16 C:/Program Files/Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2/Bin/ C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath . C:/Program Files/Tcl/bin C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath C:/WINDOWS/system32 C:/WINDOWS C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem C:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/ C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/ C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin C:/Program Files (x86)/vim/vim80 C:/tools/miniconda3 C:/tools/miniconda3/Scripts C:/Program Files/OpenSees C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mpv.install/tools C:/Program Files/Git/cmd C:/SIMULIA/Abaqus/Commands C:/Strawberry/c/bin C:/Strawberry/perl/site/bin C:/Strawberry/perl/bin C:/Users/jrm978/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps C:/Users/jrm978/AppData/Local/Pandoc/ C:/Users/jrm978/hunspell/bin C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox . C:/Program Files (x86)/clisp-2.49 c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/libexec/emacs/25.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  with-editor-emacsclient-path:
    c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin (t)
      c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/bin/emacsclient.exe (25.3)
    c:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16 (t)
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2/Bin/ (t)
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath (t)
    C:/Program Files/Tcl/bin (t)
    C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath (t)
    C:/WINDOWS/system32 (t)
    C:/WINDOWS (t)
    C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem (t)
    C:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/ (t)
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/ (t)
    C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin (t)
      C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/emacsclient.exe (25.3)
    C:/Program Files (x86)/vim/vim80 (t)
    C:/tools/miniconda3 (t)
    C:/tools/miniconda3/Scripts (t)
    C:/Program Files/OpenSees (t)
    C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mpv.install/tools (t)
    C:/Program Files/Git/cmd (t)
    C:/SIMULIA/Abaqus/Commands (t)
    C:/Strawberry/c/bin (t)
    C:/Strawberry/perl/site/bin (t)
    C:/Strawberry/perl/bin (t)
    C:/Users/jrm978/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps (t)
    C:/Users/jrm978/AppData/Local/Pandoc/ (t)
    C:/Users/jrm978/hunspell/bin (t)
    C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox (t)
    . (t)
    C:/Program Files (x86)/clisp-2.49 (t)
    c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/emacs64/tools/emacs/libexec/emacs/25.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32 (t)
```

With `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` nothing happens.

Regarding the different versions, I added the magit package when using 25.2.1, but after hitting this problem updated first emacs and then the magit package. I just removed and reinstalled magit. `M-x magit-version` now gives:

- Magit 20180517.1345, Git 2.17.0.windows.1, Emacs 25.3.1, windows-nt

But the problem persists.

Comment: Output from `M-x with-editor-debug` could be helpful. I notice that you list your Emacs version as 25.3, but your magit version listing says Emacs 25.2 (not sure if that is significant, but it seems like something worth poking at). If you run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before committing, do you get a backtrace?

Comment: Here is the `with-editor-debug` buffer:

Comment: Does it really say `server-auth-dir: ~.emacs.dserver` (with no slashes)?

Comment: It has backslashes. Perhaps freetexthost removed them. I will edit the text into the question

Answer (score 3):

After checking the results of `M-x with-editor-debug` it is evident that emacs could not access `~\.emacs.d\server`

The problem was that this directory didn't exist. After creating this as an empty directory the problem is solved.

Comment: I think Emacs is supposed to auto-create that directory as needed. It looks like it didn't happen because you somehow had an existing `server-process`.

Comment: I had a similar problem on windows, but it seems that the creation of the directory by Emacs was resulting on a folder with incorrect permissions. I deleted the folder created by Emacs and recreated it manually in windows explorer and it fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on macOS 10.15.5 Catalina. From a quick debug session I discovered that the `server` directory was also missing on my machine, like the other answer mentions.

I created it by hand, but this didn’t fix the issue.

In my case I had a Git project setup with submodules, and the submodule had `.git/gitdir` & `.git/gitfile` configurations with relative paths that were no longer present (due to a refactoring which also moved directories around). The path configured there was the same one as in the Magit error message, so I deleted the files and now I can commit again.

You’ll eventually have to check your Git submodule configuration afterwards.